# Gif animation and responsive image styles are not working

Tags: 8, media

I have a multiple image field and need it to upload images and animated gifs. These images might be resized. When this happens, the animated gif loses its animation.

Has anyone solved this problem in drupal 8?

Comment: This article might be of help: https://www.bkosborne.com/blog/preventing-drupal-8-applying-image-styles-gifs-preserve-animation

Answer (score 4):

There's now [imagemagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick) for Drupal 8. I've been using it with D8 responsive image styles and it works well, the gif animation stays intact.

You'll need to have imagemagick installed on your server and will need the path to the *convert* binary as well. Typically it's `usr/bin` or for example with MAMP, it's `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/`

Comment: According to this article, this process may result in a GIF file significantly bigger than the original: https://www.bkosborne.com/blog/preventing-drupal-8-applying-image-styles-gifs-preserve-animation